# Mysql query to concatenate distinct values from multiple column content without null and empty

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine content from multiple columns. When i try to use the following:

```
GROUP_concat(DISTINCT case when companylocation.Mobile is null then '' else companylocation.Mobile end, 
    case when companylocation.Mobile2 is null then '' else companylocation.Mobile2 end,
    case when companylocation.Mobile3 is null then '' else companylocation.Mobile3 end,
    case when companylocation.Phone3 is null then '' else companylocation.Phone3 end,
    case when companylocation.Phone4 is null then '' else companylocation.Phone4 end,
    case when Businessinfo.KeyOfficialPhone2 is null then '' else Businessinfo.KeyOfficialPhone2 end SEPARATOR ', ') as telephone
```

I get the below results.

```
3   NULL
3   9876542344NULL1800234234
3   9876542344NULL
3   NULL, NULL2663822
3   8952939102NULL
3   9811164837NULL
4   NULL2461999
5   NULL
6   9910270032NULL
6   9540828102NULL
8   9440601141NULL
9   9414131222NULL
10  9842731310NULL2252608
```

But when i try the following query

```
   GROUP_concat(DISTINCT concat(case when (length(companylocation.Mobile) > 0 AND (companylocation.Mobile=NULL)) then concat(companylocation.Mobile, ', ') else concat(companylocation.Mobile) end), 
    concat(case when length(companylocation.Mobile2) > 0 then concat(companylocation.Mobile2, ', ') else concat(companylocation.Mobile2) end),
    concat(case when length(companylocation.Mobile3) > 0 then concat(companylocation.Mobile3, ', ') else concat(companylocation.Mobile3) end),
    concat(case when length(companylocation.Phone3) > 0 then concat(companylocation.Phone3, ', ') else concat(companylocation.Phone3) end),
    concat(case when length(companylocation.Phone4) > 0 then concat(companylocation.Phone4, ', ') else concat(companylocation.Phone4) end),
    concat(case when length(Businessinfo.KeyOfficialPhone2) > 0 then concat(Businessinfo.KeyOfficialPhone2, ', ') else concat(Businessinfo.KeyOfficialPhone2) end) SEPARATOR ', ' ) as telephone
```

I get the all "null" results.

What i want is as below:

```
3   9876542344, 1800234234
10  9842731310, 2252608
```

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Can you post the complete query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `group_concat()` in a query with a `group by`.  I suspect you want something like this with the right `group by`:

```
GROUP_concat(DISTINCT
             concat_ws(', ', companylocation.Mobile, companylocation.Mobile2, 
                       companylocation.Mobile3, companylocation.Phone3, companylocation.Phone4, 
                       Businessinfo.KeyOfficialPhone2)
             separator ', ')
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you for your quick response. it concatenating but also including blanks. Below is the result for your query. `3, , NULL, , 
3, 9876542344, NULL, 1800234234, 
3, 9876542344, NULL, , 
3, , NULL, 2663822, , , NULL, , 
3, 8952939102, NULL, , 
3, 9811164837, NULL, , 
4, , NULL, 2461999
5, , NULL, , 
6, 9910270032, NULL, , 
6, 9540828102, NULL, , 
8, 9440601141, NULL, , 
9, 9414131222, NULL, , 
10, 9842731310, NULL, , 2252608`